# Codechef recipe wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why am I getting a wrong answer to this question? The program gives correct answers to the example testcases.

Question link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/RECIPE

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    ingredients,*items = map(int,input().split())   
    if (0 not in items):
        trial = [x%min(items)==0 for x in items]    
        if all(trial):
            print(*[int(x//min(items)) for x in items ])
        else:
            print(*items)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing all of the numbers by `min(items)` works for the sample cases they give, but it isn't sufficiently general. Consider the third sample case:

> 3 15 9 6

Dividing everything by 3 gives the correct answer. But what if I changed the 3 to a 6?

> **6** 15 9 6

Dividing by 3 would still be the correct strategy, but 3 doesn't appear in the input. (Dividing by 6 doesn't work because 15 and 9 are odd numbers.)

The right way to do this is to find the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), or GCD. The GCD is the largest number that divides each of the numbers. If you don't know how to calculate the GCD I'll challenge you to try to figure it out without looking up how. If you get stuck you can look up an algorithm, but it's a simple enough adjustment to what you already have that you should be able to do it yourself.